# Azure Linux turbo boost not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, turbo-boost

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS running in Microsoft Azure F-series virtual machine (F4s at the moment). Supposedly it has "2.4 GHz Intel Xeon® E5-2673 v3 (Haswell) processor, which can achieve clock speeds as high as 3.2 GHz with the Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0".

However, both `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` and `sudo turbostat` show, that all cores are running at 2394MHz.

Even after I ran single-threaded busy loop and `top` reported, that one of the cores is at 100%, clockrate still did not change. Even after I ran one single-threaded busy loop for each core and top reported, that all cores are at 100%, clockrate still stayed at 2394MHz.

Kernel is 4.4.0-45-generic and msr module is loaded.

Has anyone gotten 3.2GHz working and if so, how? What could I do to further pinpoint the location of the problem? How should I go about resolving it?

---

Edit: I would like to re-iterate, that I am talking about a virtual machine inside Microsoft Azure cloud service where I have no control over physical hardware nor the pre-boot environment (in fact the hardware is abstracted away and managed by service provider). My believef that using Turbo Boost 'should' be possible is based on information available from Microsoft websites that suggest it being enabled ( [more information about F-Series VM-s](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/#f-series) ).

Comment: You want an H series Azure VM if want Boost.  The other series do not specifically indicate that boost is enabled, which tells me, it is not.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/ states that it's also on the Dv2 range, and the F range

Answer (score 0):

Azure currently does not expose turbo frequency to guest OS. That is why you can only see base frequency information, even though the CPUs are actually running at turbo frequency